# Rcpp functions delivery

Tags: rcpp

I have made some Rcpp functions for some on-going work, but the work may be performed my colleagues who are R beginners. My question is, if my colleagues want to use these function on their machines, do they have to install Rtools and use sourceRcpp() to compile the functions first? Is that any way I can avoid this? For example, use the function just like using require()? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On *any* OS, R permits you to provide a *binary* package. On Windows and OS X, this is even common.  You did not (explicitly) state what OS your colleagues use; from context (Rtools?) it is presumably Windows.  You could even use the [win-builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org) service to compile it.

This is *very basic* packaging question, which is addressed in the [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) manual.  There is nothing particular about Rcpp here.

We do however have an entire vignette on packaging which you should read, and the material is also covered in the [Rcpp book](http://www.rcpp.org/book).

Comment: Thanks Dirk. My OS is Windows 7 64 Bit Prof. I will have some try. Also ,the link of Rcpp Book does not work.